# no days off : translation?

Tags: translation, word-choice, idiomaticity

**In short:** What would be the idiomatic German equivalent of "no days off!" if it means "you have to work/exercise every day"? Is there anything better than **"Kein Tag ohne arbeiten/lehren, usw."**?

**Full story:**
I was talking with my students about [the Latin motto "Nulla dies sine linea"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulla_dies_sine_linea). I explained to them the French meaning of this phrase and the discussion continued about the reason for using such a phrase. We were particularly interested in the galvanising aspect of this expression; we imagined students preparing for a competition or sportsmen training every day. Then I compared the Latin sentence to the English phrase "no days off!" and I felt my students appreciated the brevity of those three words. Then someone asked me if I knew how to translate "no days off!" in German.
I asked a German colleague: she answered she didn't know an exact translation except for **"Kein Tag ohne arbeiten/lehren, usw."**.

Is there a German equivalent that does justice to the brevity of the English sentence?

Comment: There is a verb that comes to mind, but it is specific to the Allemanic dialect (spoken in southwest Germany and Switzerland): **"Schaffe"**. Two notes here: - In standard German, the verb **schaffen** translates either _"to accomplish"_ or _"to create"_, but in all Upper German dialects it just means _"to work"_.
- In Allemanic, the infinitive form of a verb ends with -e, not -en like in standard German, so the above is not an imperative. Unlike other regions of southern Germany, in the Allemanic parts, especially [Swabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabia), the verb _"schaffe"_ is often u

Comment: Perhaps an idiomatic saying that tries to express something  similar: "Wer rastet, der rostet" (~ a rolling stone gather no moss). Or, known form an old petrol advertising: "Es gibt viel zu tun, packen wir es an"

Answer (score 10):

**Kein freier Tag!**

The simple imperative; German is well suited as a command language ;-)
Of course it can be embellished, or in another context becomes a complaint...

Comment: An imperative requires a verb, but there is none.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich It really depends on how you define imperative. You seem to prefer a syntactic point of view, understanding imperativ as the mood of a verb. From a pragmatical point of view, _Kein freier Tag!_ could well be called an imperative as it expresses a direction or an order.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, there is "[…] a German equivalent that does justice to the brevity of the English […]" phrase:

> to have **no day off**
>  ⇒ 
> **keinen Tag frei** haben

Comment: I'm not sure how that's meant to be an imperative. Perhaps something like: *Hab keinen freien Tag.*

Comment: @RDBury, yes, the [imperative forms of *haben*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:haben#Imperativ) are *habe (du)*, *habt (ihr)*, and *haben (Sie)*.

Comment: @RDBury "No time off!" also has no imperative verb form. "Keinen Tag frei!" is a similar exclamation.

Answer (score 8):

My suggestion is

*Keine Auszeit.*

Comment: Best translation of the ones offered here, imho.

Answer (score 1):

The German Bauhaus movement artist Paul Klee used the translation of the Latin original you mention as his maxim: "Kein Tag ohne Linie". But also, I think "kein Tag frei" is sufficiently idiomatic — there is a rap song with this title and its use communicates a similar ethos of constant effort without rest. Certainly not my sort of music, but nevertheless a functional example of the phrase in use.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest "pausenlos" or "ohne Unterbrechung".

Comment: Finde ich unpassend; das würde bedeuten, 24h / Tag zu arbeiten oder trainieren.

Comment: @Robert Was bedeutet dann der Satz "Für jeden vierten jungen Beschäftigten ist es normal, pausenlos zu arbeiten"? Vgl. https://www.haufe.de/arbeitsschutz/gesundheit-umwelt/pausenlos-arbeiten-junge-arbeitskraefte-goennen-sich-keine-ruhe_94_338686.html

Comment: @PaulFrost Das bedeutet, dass jemand völlig übertreibt und ich die Aussage extrem unglaubwürdig finde. Wahrscheinlich machen die Leute auch keine Klo- oder Kippenpausen. Ich würde ja sagen, sie schlafen unter ihrem Schreibtisch, aber das wäre ja auch eine Unterbrechung, kann also auch nicht sein.